# Setting up a Proxy to record Firefox requests

Tags: ruby, firefox, ubuntu, proxy, watir

I'm using Ruby+Watir to request pages through Firefox.

I would like to record the headers and content of every http request made through the browser.

Would it be possible to configure a proxy solution to store this information, either in a file or pipe it straight into an application? Could I use something such as squid or nginx to record header/content information?

PS: Running Ubuntu x64.

Comment: This might be better on superuser.com..

Comment: You should take a look browsermob-proxy. And there is also a ruby gem client to create multiple proxies. The rest api allows to get a har(network traffics, including request heahers) for the current proxy.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a proxy, you could just use tcpdump e.g.
tcpdump -i en0 -n -s 0 -w output.pcap

You can then retrospectively look at all traffic in wireshark etc.

The BrowserMob proxy might be a good fit for you (runs as a jar file)

You could also roll your own in Ruby (but only works with HTTP, not HTTPS)
e.g.

```
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'webrick/httpproxy'

  @proxy_port    = ARGV[0] || 9090

  # Optional flags
  @print_headers  = false
  @print_body     = true

  server = WEBrick::HTTPProxyServer.new(
    :Port => @proxy_port,
    :AccessLog => [],
    :ProxyContentHandler => Proc.new do |req,res|
        puts "-"*75
        puts ">>> #{req.request_line.chomp}\n"
        req.header.keys.each { |key| puts "#{key.capitalize}: #{req.header[key]}" if @print_headers }
        puts "<<<" if @print_headers
        puts res.status_line if @print_headers
        res.header.keys.each { |key| puts "#{key.capitalize}: #{res.header[key]}" if @print_headers }
        puts res.body unless res.body.nil? or !@print_body
    end
  )
  trap("INT") { server.shutdown }
  server.start
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows there is a program called [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) that does exactly what you need, so I did a Google search for "[Fiddler for Linux](http://www.google.com/search?q=fiddler+for+linux)" and came up with [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/). Looks pretty strong.

I didn't notice the price tag for the non-trial version of Charles. Another app worth looking into is [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2691), an add-on for Firefox. It is not clear to me whether it captures all traffic or only returns response for directly input requests, but still could help you with your project.

Comment: I'm actually using Charles for testing, and although I love its export->XML feature, I can't automate it because it doesn't allow that. It also has memory limitations, because it stores all of the information in memory (according to the docs).
Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Oh that's lame. 50 bucks for something that can't write to disk. I wish the Firebug history tool would be updated already.